# How to index internal transactions in subgraph?

Tags: the-graph, subgraph

I'm trying to create a subgraph using callHandlers.  It doesn't seem to index function calls that come from a smart contract, only EOAs.  Is there a way I can ensure these are included in the subgraph?

Here's my `subgraph.yaml`

```
specVersion: 0.0.2
schema:
  file: ./schema.graphql
dataSources:
  - kind: ethereum
    name: Vesting
    network: mainnet
    source:
      address: "0x2B79E11984514Ece5B2Db561F49c0466cC7659EA"
      abi: Vesting
      startBlock: 13369330
    mapping:
      kind: ethereum/events
      apiVersion: 0.0.5
      language: wasm/assemblyscript
      entities:
        - Claim
      abis:
        - name: Vesting
          file: ./abis/Vesting.json
      callHandlers:
        - function: setVestingSchedule(address,uint256,bool) 
          handler: handleSetVestingSchedule
        - function: claim()
          handler: handleClaim
        - function: cancelVesting(address)
          handler: handleCancel
      file: ./src/mapping.ts
```

I know that the `setVestingSchedule` function was called from a smart contract, but none of those events are being indexed

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the 'calling contract' to your yaml file. I know that only the events emitted by the two contracts I added to my subgraph have their entities tracked. Less actually as I removed one event for one contract from my yaml.